# How is Ctrl + Z interpreted in the Windows terminal?

Tags: c++, terminal, cin, eof, getline

I ran the program given below. I am aware of the recommendation to use `while (std::getline(std::cin, inp))` instead of `while (!std::cin.eof())`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    while (!std::cin.eof()) {

        std::string next_line;
        std::getline(std::cin, next_line);

        if (!std::cin) {
            std::cout << "failbit has been set";
            return 0;
        }

        if (next_line.empty()) {
            std::cout << "input line was empty";
            return 0;
        }

    }

    std::cout << "Success!";

}
```

Below I give some example input and the program response. ^Z indicates that I typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

In this first example, I typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> twice across two lines and saw the expected behavior of reaching EOF without flipping the failbit.

Input 1:

```
this is
my input
and this is the
end^Z
^Z
```

Output 1:

```
Success!
```

In this second example, I was able to add two extra newlines at the end of my input after typing a single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, however, the `eofbit` was not toggled.

Input 2:

```
this is
my input
and this is the
end^Z
```

Output 2:

```
input line was empty
```

In this third example, I saw the expected output of the failbit of `std::cin` being set. My understanding is that if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> is the EOF, `std::getline` should set the `eofbit` of `std::cin`, but would not yet set the `failbit`. This is based on line 2 (a) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). The "failbit has been set" output should not be given under normal inputs.

Input 3:

```
this is
my input
and this is the
end
^Z
```

Output 3:

```
failbit has been set
```

What is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> doing in each of these examples?

Comment: @Damien the actual question is not the title, but the question at the bottom of the post: "What is Ctrl+ Z doing in each of these examples?" It does not appear to me that every ^Z in my inputs is functioning as an EOF. (Furthermore, some of the posts I have read have suggested that there is no EOF character, and that EOF is a state reached at the end of input... or something like that.)

Comment: In Windows the end of input is the ^Z if it appears on a line by itself.  If it isn't on a line by itself then it is just a normal character.  On Linux the equivalent is ^D. This might help: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040316-00/?p=40233

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks, that helps, but I don't see then why Input 2 worked the way it did. Why am I allowed to input empty lines without triggering  "input line was empty"?

Comment: Furthermore, why do Inputs 1 and 3 give different outputs?

Comment: @user589321 It doesn't print "input line was empty" because you are returning when `!std::cin`, so it never had the chance to print that