# Does getline() always toggle the failbit when it reaches EOF when using Windows console?

Tags: c++, windows, cin, eof, getline

Based on posts I've read and my own testing, to send an EOF character in the Windows terminal, the user must type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> on its own line and press enter. For example, example 1 sends EOF, but example 2 does not:

Example 1:

```
this is a test
of EOF in Windows
^Z
```

Example 2:

```
this is a test
of EOF in Windows^Z
```

Example 1 will toggle both the `failbit` and the `eofbit` when `getline` is called. I have been trying to figure out how I would toggle `eofbit` without toggling the `failbit`. To better understand what was happening, I checked the source code for `getline` in MSVC:

```
// FUNCTION TEMPLATE getline
template <class _Elem, class _Traits, class _Alloc>
basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>& getline(basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>&& _Istr,
    basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>& _Str,
    const _Elem _Delim) { // get characters into string, discard delimiter
    using _Myis = basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>;

    typename _Myis::iostate _State = _Myis::goodbit;
    bool _Changed                  = false;
    const typename _Myis::sentry _Ok(_Istr, true);

    if (_Ok) { // state okay, extract characters
        _TRY_IO_BEGIN
        _Str.erase();
        const typename _Traits::int_type _Metadelim = _Traits::to_int_type(_Delim);
        typename _Traits::int_type _Meta            = _Istr.rdbuf()->sgetc();

        for (;; _Meta = _Istr.rdbuf()->snextc()) {
            if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(), _Meta)) { // end of file, quit
                _State |= _Myis::eofbit;
                break;
            } else if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Meta, _Metadelim)) { // got a delimiter, discard it and quit
                _Changed = true;
                _Istr.rdbuf()->sbumpc();
                break;
            } else if (_Str.max_size() <= _Str.size()) { // string too large, quit
                _State |= _Myis::failbit;
                break;
            } else { // got a character, add it to string
                _Str += _Traits::to_char_type(_Meta);
                _Changed = true;
            }
        }
        _CATCH_IO_(_Myis, _Istr)
    }

    if (!_Changed) {
        _State |= _Myis::failbit;
    }

    _Istr.setstate(_State);
    return _Istr;
}
```

In example 1, when you call `getline()` the third time, the function must terminate with `_Changed = false;` because `^Z` is on its own line. This means that the failbit will be set here:

```
    if (!_Changed) {
        _State |= _Myis::failbit;
    }
```

As in example 2, you cannot send EOF in a line that causes `_Changed = true;`. This is because a delimiter would cause you to break out of `for (;; _Meta = _Istr.rdbuf()->snextc()) {` without reaching EOF, and EOF cannot be sent on the same line as a non-EOF, non-delimiter in the Windows console.

My question is this: **can you toggle the `std::cin` `eofbit` using `getline(std::cin, inp_str)` and interfacing through the Windows terminal without toggling the `std::cin` `failbit`?**

#### EDIT

This code demonstrates the behaviors described above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    while (!std::cin.eof()) {

        std::string next_line;
        std::getline(std::cin, next_line);

        if (std::cin.eof()) {
            std::cout << "EOF reached\n";
        }

        if (!std::cin) {
            std::cout << "failbit set";
            return 0;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

With example 1 as input, this code terminates with both `eofbit` and `failbit` set.

With example 2 as input, this code does not terminate.

I have a second, closely related question here:

[How is Ctrl + Z interpreted in the Windows terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333279/how-is-ctrl-z-interpreted-in-the-windows-terminal)

Comment: Are you feeding this input stream from a file redirected into your running executable?  Or are you entering this information line-by-line, manually?  If the later, then the behavior is affected by the read line of the terminal (or CMD shell) before it ever gets to the running program.

Comment: @Eljay entering it manually in the terminal (Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console)

Comment: The Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console is probably eating the character in the one case, and passing it through in the other case.